# Create PDF of a https webpage which requires login using pdfkit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdfkit

I am trying to generate a PDF of a webpage from a https website (Salesforce).
I have so far tried using simple_salesforce, which returns a sessionID (cookie) to no avail.

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pdfkit

sf = Salesforce(username='my username'
            ,password='my password'
            ,security_token= 'my API security token')

path_wkthmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=bytes(path_wkthmltopdf, 'utf8'))
options1 = {
    'page-size': None,
    'margin-top': None,
    'margin-right': None,
    'margin-bottom': None,
    'margin-left': None,
    'encoding': None,
    'custom-header' : None, 
    'cookie': sf.session_id,
    'no-outline': None
}
pdfkit.from_url('https://thiess.my.salesforce.com/0069000000IZH71','out.pdf', 
                configuration=config, options=options1)
```

Anyone knows what's the best way to pass a cookie argument into pdfkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this :) You probably need requests, if you don't have. I don't know much about the salesforce library.

```
import requests
import pdfkit

session = requests.session()


def download(session,username,password):
    session.get('https://bneadf.thiess.com.au/adfs/ls/')

    ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': self.ua}
    payload = {'UserName':username,
        'Password':password,
        'AuthMethod':'FormsAuthentication'}

    session.post('https://bneadf.thiess.com.au/adfs/ls/', data = payload, headers = session.headers)
    my_html = session.get('https://thiess.my.salesforce.com/0069000000IZH71')
    my_pdf = open('myfile.html','wb+')
    my_pdf.write(my_html.content)
    my_pdf.close()

    path_wkthmltopdf = 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=bytes(path_wkthmltopdf, 'utf8'))


    pdfkit.from_file('myfile.html', 'out.pdf')

download(session,"yourusername","yourpass")
```

Comment: There's a few typos in the script but after fixing them the thing worked, but only kinda. Apparently the html format generated from the request.get call distorted the layout of the webpage so although the contents were there, the appearance is totally different. Do you know of any other format that better preserve the appearance of the page?

Comment: Then you should use the same method, but with BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Beautiful soup returns links to images which when passed to pdfkit, runs into the same problem of pdfkit not being about to handle the authentication process by itself.

Comment: I notice that pdfkit has a cookie option and simple_salesforce returns session_id as well as header and session.cookie, I tried passing them as argument but I could not get the format right

Answer (score 4):

For using pdfkit in Django to access a protected view, just pass along the cookies in the from_url() function call.

```
cookie_list = request.COOKIES
# pass the cookies. You can add whatever other options you want to use
options = {
        'cookie' : [
            ('csrftoken', cookie_list['csrftoken']),
            ('sessionid', cookie_list['sessionid']),
            ]
        }

# Generate the pdf
pdf = pdfkit.from_url(url_to_page,False, options=options)
```

I also had a hard time with it because just passing in the cookie dictionary doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I am having a similar issue as well. I noticed there is an advanced options setting on the github/documetation where you can pass cookies and a cookiejar along with a username and password. I know that this seems to be something that you tried but it looks like you did not set the cookie name correctly. Here is the docs from https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit

```
options = {
  'page-size': 'Letter',
  'margin-top': '0.75in',
  'margin-right': '0.75in',
  'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
  'margin-left': '0.75in',
  'encoding': "UTF-8",
  'custom-header' : [
      ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip')
  ]
  'cookie': [
      ('cookie-name1', 'cookie-value1'),
      ('cookie-name2', 'cookie-value2'),
  ],
  'no-outline': None
}

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf', options=options)
```

It seems that for the 'cookie' object you need to pass in a list with the cookie name and value as tuples. I havent been able to get it to work on my example, I think because my webpage uses a lot of javascript/css. However, using the requests method that Attila mentioned you might be able to do something with the salesforce login?

```
cookie_list = session.cookies.items()
```

then maybe try your example again?

```
options1 = {
  'page-size': None,
  'margin-top': None,
  'margin-right': None,
  'margin-bottom': None,
  'margin-left': None,
  'encoding': None,
  'custom-header' : None, 
  'cookie': cookie_list,
  'no-outline': None
}
```