# Links from list - How to generate several pdf's using python pdfkit

Tags: python, list, web, pdfkit

I am currently trying to figure out how i can take a list of links and make python run through all of them and save them as pdf. (I'm not a python expert)

I found a python package called "pdfkit" which is quite good, but how do i set it up so that it follow my url-list and save the pdf as different names all the time?

```
import pdfkit

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe")

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'MyPDF.pdf', configuration=config)
```

This is my current code, lets say that i have a list of 10 webpages that i want to save as 10 different pdf files how do i make a setup that would allow me to do so?

Another issue is that i need to login to the page in order to scrape the information from the links, how would you implement that?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for the first question:

```
import pdfkit

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe")

url_list = [
    ['http://google.com', 'google.com.pdf'],
    ['http://facebook.com', 'facebook.com.pdf'],
    ['http://yahoo.com', 'yahoo.com.pdf'],
]

for k, v in url_list:
    pdfkit.from_url(k, v, configuration=config)
```

For answer to the second question, you can use the requests module session feature to login first and then pass the cookie to pdfkit to download the page. See [Create PDF of a https webpage which requires login using pdfkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644929/create-pdf-of-a-https-webpage-which-requires-login-using-pdfkit)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i went with another solution, but it keeps giving me an error saying the code follows below                                                                                                                          File "C:\Users\Jeppe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfkit\configuration.py", line 21, in __init__
    with open(self.wkhtmltopdf) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b''

Comment: I couldnt make it stick as code when posting comment so i posted the code below in the answer

Comment: Btw how do i implement the url_list that you created for me in the code down below?

Answer (score 0):

```
import selenium.webdriver
import pdfkit
import time

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf="C:\\Program Files 
(x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe")

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/')
time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element_by_id('login-email').send_keys('username')
driver.find_element_by_id('login-password').send_keys('password')
driver.find_element_by_id('login-submit').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.save_screenshot('output.png') # only visible part

print(driver.page_source)
pdfkit.from_string(driver.page_source, 'file.pdf')
```